# Scaling Node.js App - Which provider?

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-web-services

I have been working with a couple Node.js frameworks to create applications of which I typically use Heroku to deploy. Recently I came across this disclaimer on Derby's documentation page that states:

> Note that while Derby supports multiple servers, it currently requires
>   that clients repeatedly connect to the same server. Heroku does not
>   support sticky sessions or WebSockets, so it isn’t possible to use
>   more than one dyno. You’ll have to use a different hosting option to
>   scale your app.

This is obviously concerning for scalability. Because of the statement above, I understand it is not a Node limitation, but a Heroku limitation.

First, is this accurate? That is - I cannot scale Node apps on Heroku?

If that is the truth, where should I turn?  AWS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derby is not a typical Node.js app. Derby (and Meteor) are essentially complete frameworks built on top of Node. Websockets is not yet supported on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

However, the typical alternative to sticky sessions for regular Node apps is to use a datastore like Redis (or Postgres or Mongo) to store session data. This is a far more robust approach than sticky sessions, as it's resilient to the failure of any particular device.

Take a look at http://12factor.net/ for more info on horizontal scaling.

Comment: Ah, this explains a lot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help. Please approve the answer if it met your needs.